# Cannot set the checkbox using a given custom class

Tags: android, checkbox, spinner

I'm following these classes in order to get a spinner with an item and a checkbox:

[android spinner dropdown checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417984/android-spinner-dropdown-checkbox)

The problem is, I can't actually maintain the state of the checkbox. I'm able to set them giving them a value from a Database, but When I close the spinner to click on update (and send the values to the BD), the values reset. I've been spending many hours in a working solution, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended erasing the class and using another method.