# How can I retrieve Multiple Check selection from alertdialog on activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

[image: Get Selected Data]

I had bind `AlertDialog` with list in `RecyclerView`. I am not able to retrieve the data from `RecyclerView` adapter.

Here is my activity where I need to get data

```
package com.labs.ankitt.hma;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import com.labs.ankitt.hma.databinding.ActivityHealthBinding;
import com.labs.ankitt.hma.databinding.ItemRecyclerContainerBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HealthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ActivityHealthBinding healthBinding;
    private ItemRecyclerContainerBinding containerBinding;
    private ChoiceAdapter adapter;

    private List<Health> healthList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Health health;
    private String user[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        healthBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_health);

        addList();
        setListener();
    }

    private void addList() {
        user = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.person_array);
        for (String anUser : user) {
            health = new Health();
            health.setTitle(anUser);
            healthList.add(health);
        }
    }

    private void setListener() {
        healthBinding.buttonPerson.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == healthBinding.buttonPerson) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            containerBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_recycler_container, null, false);
            alert.setView(containerBinding.getRoot());
            alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            adapter= new ChoiceAdapter(this, healthList);
            containerBinding.recyclerContiner.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            containerBinding.recyclerContiner.setHasFixedSize(true);
            containerBinding.recyclerContiner.setAdapter(adapter);
            AlertDialog dialog= alert.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is adapter I had written for getting and handling the check selection in `RecyclerView`

```
 package com.labs.ankitt.hma;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.labs.ankitt.hma.databinding.RowItemDataBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChoiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChoiceAdapter.ChoiceHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Health> healthList;
    private ArrayList<Void> mCheckedState;
    private Health health;

    public ChoiceAdapter(Context context, List<Health> healthList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.healthList = healthList;
        mCheckedState = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChoiceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RowItemDataBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                R.layout.row_item_data, null, false);
        ChoiceHolder holder = new ChoiceHolder(dataBinding.getRoot(), dataBinding);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChoiceHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        health = healthList.get(position);
        holder.itemDataBinding.checkBoxUser.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                health = healthList.get(position);
                if (isChecked) {
                    health.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    health.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.itemDataBinding.checkBoxUser.setChecked(healthList.get(position).isChecked());

        getSelection(healthList.get(position));
        Log.i("Test", "onBindViewHolder: " +healthList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.itemDataBinding.checkTextUser.setText(health.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return healthList.size();
    }

    public class ChoiceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RowItemDataBinding itemDataBinding;

        public ChoiceHolder(View itemView, RowItemDataBinding dataBinding) {
            super(itemView);
            itemDataBinding = dataBinding;
        }
    }

    public String getSelection(Health health) {
        return health.getTitle();
    }
}
```

How to get data from Recycler Adapter to main screen.

Comment: You may want to check the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417984/android-spinner-dropdown-checkbox on how to do this for a checkable spinner adapter. Not exactly the same, but you might get some ideas

Answer (score 0):

**Your code can be shrinked to some lines.**

### Best Approach

You can easily set a `AlertDialog` with `CheckBox` list. That is provided by Android itself. Here is how you do that.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" A "," B "," C "," D "};

final ArrayList seletedItems=new ArrayList();

AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Select One")
.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
        } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
            seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
        }
    }
}).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //  Your code when user clicked on OK
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       //todo
    }
}).create();
dialog.show();
```

## Edition for your code (If you want know)

So you were doing wrong that just made single `Health` object globally, and changing its value at `checkChange`. That lead to change single object for every item of list. You can achieve like this.

By the below code you can get selected items list by method `adapter.getSelectedList()`.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class classss extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChoiceAdapter.ChoiceHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Health> healthList;

    public ChoiceAdapter(Context context, List<Health> healthList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.healthList = healthList;
    }

    public List<Health> getSelectedList() {
        List<Health> selected = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Health h : healthList) {
            if (h.isChecked()) {
                selected.add(h);
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChoiceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RowItemDataBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                R.layout.row_item_data, null, false);
        ChoiceHolder holder = new ChoiceHolder(dataBinding.getRoot(), dataBinding);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChoiceHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        Health health = healthList.get(position);
        holder.itemDataBinding.checkBoxUser.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                health.setChecked(isChecked)
            }
        });
        holder.itemDataBinding.checkBoxUser.setChecked(health.isChecked());
        holder.itemDataBinding.checkTextUser.setText(health.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return healthList.size();
    }

    public class ChoiceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RowItemDataBinding itemDataBinding;

        public ChoiceHolder(View itemView, RowItemDataBinding dataBinding) {
            super(itemView);
            itemDataBinding = dataBinding;
        }
    }

    public String getSelection(Health health) {
        return health.getTitle();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want me to edit your code, then tell me, but best approach is this above.

Comment: No my condition are different I need to handle the check when closed and reopen of the alertdialog also I want to update the check with coming arraylist from webservice [Need Help For this Code](https://gist.github.com/ankittale/58638977d71f46d4e9da03279fd148b3)

Comment: Condition are I want to handle check selection while closing and reopening hold check and update that check with webservice