# How to add 2 columns of checkboxes in Spinner dropdown

Tags: android, checkbox, spinner

I have a spinner I want to add  two columns of checkboxes in the drop down of spinner.

I have tried this solution [android spinner dropdown checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417984/android-spinner-dropdown-checkbox)
but this does not let me show a hint "Please Select..." when no item is selected.

Here is what I want.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11cr0iPgs9vwULeGeTAtllFR-3KW-6YvM

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, standard spinner doesn't allow to show 'nothing selected' state after adapter is set. As soon as you set adapter first element become selected.

You should create custrom spinner for "nothing selected" position. See here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12221309](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221309)

Seems, you should join solution from this link with link from your question