# How to get value from this multi select spinner and save it to String?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I confuse about printing checked data from multi select spinner to textview, what should i do ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418249/11182330

Answer (score 0):

From @Ironman's solution, he maintains an `ArrayList` of items inside the activity itself, and its values are updated.

You have access to it from within your activity.

```java
ArrayList<StateVO> listVOs = new ArrayList<>();
....
....
....
....

for(StateVo state: listVOs)
    if (state.isSelected())
        Log.d(state.getTitle()); //Will print all of the selected items in your log.
```

Regarding `TextView` - I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, it's not very aesthetic. Please explain what is it exactly that you want to do, and I'll edit my answer for you.